# Render Github Gist file as Apex

Tags: github, salesforce, apex, gist

I'd like to set my file extension's for GitHub Gists to Apex so that the code's rendered correctly. But I can't work out which extension to use or find a reference guide.

I've tried `.cls`, `.tgr` having found this [Success answer](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gsFPAAY) but neither are recognized by GitHub.

[image: Gist Extension examples]

I've also tested `.apx` & `.apex` but they don't work either.

What should I use instead?

Answer (score 0):

GitHub have now told me that they use the open source project Linguist to Id the file extensions.

Apex [is included](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/07173d2238777736d2be2aa04825e24c632ee984/lib/linguist/languages.yml#L168-L173) but as I mentioned .cls isn't being recognized correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Since **linguist** just maps Apex to Java anyhow, this best approach is to simply use the extension `.java` for your Apex Gists.

That being said, using `.cls` seemed to work OK - but its hard to tell if it was using the VB parser.  Given Apex is based on Java, the `.java` extension is a safer bet.

https://gist.github.com/shanekenyon87/6cdf17bd734eb421c8defbf836665e55